# Initialize service without passing it in as an argument

Tags: angularjs

I have some legacy AngularJS code that looks like the following:

```
angular
    .module('MyModule')
    .directive('MyDirective', [])
    .controller('MyController', [
        'MyDependency',
        function(myDependency) { // ... })
    ]);
```

In this case, the argument `myDependency` is not being used anywhere in the code and I do not believe we should pass it in just for the sake of initializing `MyDependency`. Is there a way to initialize `MyDependency` without passing it in as an argument here? Based on some of my research, I am leaning towards using the [$injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector) service.

Comment: your question is unclear...

Answer (score 0):

Consider injecting the service in a `.run` block:

```
angular
    .module('MyModule')
    .directive('MyDirective', [])
    ̶.̶c̶o̶n̶t̶r̶o̶l̶l̶e̶r̶(̶'̶M̶y̶C̶o̶n̶t̶r̶o̶l̶l̶e̶r̶'̶,̶ ̶[̶
    .run(['MyDependency',
          function(myDependency) { /* ... */ })
    ]);
```

Dependencies injected in `.run` blocks are instantiated and initialized before directives and controllers.